# Why is Spring 4.0.9 applicationContext initialization getting stuck but not 3.2.1?

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

My applicationContext initialization was working fine with Spring 3.2.1.

But when I upgraded to 4.0.9 without changing any code or bean definitions), the initialization got stuck. The following statement kept on happening. There's no  obvious circular reference though.

```
Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I continued to investigate. I deliberately removed a bean definition.

- Spring 3.2.1 had the expected outcome: threw a fatal error almost immediately.
- Spring 4.0.9 was still getting into this infinite loop, trying to find a different seed bean definition to make things work.

Here's the log statement that kept on happening.

```
[factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean()] - Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'someSeedBean-which-is-different-in-every-instance-of-this-log' defined in the class path resource ........ ; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'someDataSource' is defined
```

What's changed? Any ideas would be helpful.

---

Bean definitions that work in both Spring 3.x and 4.x

```
<bean id="abstractDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" abstract="true" scope="singleton">
        <property ....>
</bean>

<bean id="someDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" scope="singleton" parent="abstractDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" .... />   
</bean>

<bean id="someSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"> <ref bean="someDataSource" />  </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan"> <list>......</list> </property>
    ....
```

Bean definitions that work in Spring 3.x but not in 4.0.9.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeSpringConfiguration{

    // Moving this beanDef to Java for features not available in XML
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource someDataSource() { // also tried setting this to ComboPooledDataSource
        // verified that this beanDefinition is recognized by Spring
        // but this bean is never created / this method is never executed
        ...
        return datasource;
    }
}     

<bean class="SomeSpringConfiguration" />

<bean id="someSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"> <ref bean="someDataSource" />  </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan"> <list>......</list> </property>
    ....
</bean>
```

Error I get with Spring 4.0.9 is

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'someSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'someSessionFactory': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Please note that the application has thousands of beans defined in/via xml, @Component, and @Configuration. I had to move above bean from xml to a @Configuration class to execute a complicated bean build procedure.

-----------------------UPDATE

I found the issue: 'tons of MethodInvokingFactoryBean[MIB] usages'. For some reason, Spring 4 was getting confused in presence of tons of MIBs. The exact same code base worked fine with Spring 3. I migrated all the logic performed by various MIBs to an ApplicationListener. Please note that ApplicationListener is not an intended replacement for MIBs but in my case I could reproduce the logic in a listener because the MIBs were just performing static injection of Spring beans into classes not managed by Spring. It not only fixed this issue but decreased Spring startup time to ~200 seconds from ~300 seconds.

Unfortunately, I neither could figure out the root cause in Spring nor could reproduce the issue in a smaller code-base (to share here).

Comment: Do you have a bean named someDataSource, can we see it's definition, does it have any dependencies, can we see them?

Comment: @RC Posted bean definitions. Please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Remove

```
<bean class="SomeSpringConfiguration" />
```

from XML, it's already annotated with `@Configuration`. If it's being scanned it's likely the beans in it are getting created twice. You should move everything into Javaconfig.

Comment: Thanks for response. I removed the suggested line but the autoscanning was not enabled for the package of SomeSpringConfiguration. So I added `<context:component-scan base-package="package.of.SomeSpringConfiguration" />. Still no luck; it's running into infinite loop.  Btw, please check the new detail added at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1):

Circular references are common during development, when you have a lot of beans and are not careful when you autowire them together. The stacktrace should contain the complete list of beans, telling you where the circular reference starts and ends.

**I have never seen random circular references** (and I encountered circular references many times over the last 7 years)! As far as I know, the code that builds the dependency tree and instantiates/wire the beans is deterministic. So you should always get the same circular reference every time you run. If you don't, I can only thing of two reasons

- There is a bug in the Spring version you are using (I'm 99% sure there is a unit test for this)
- You have one of more beans that starts a thread as part of bean instantiation, and the thread uses the applicationContext to load another bean lazily (while the context is still loading).

When I teach Spring classes, I recommend that constructors should only contain field assignments, if you need to start threads (or anything else with a lifecycle) you should use the lifecycle methods. Personally I prefer to implement SmartLifeCycle (over InitializingBean/DisposableBean, @PostConstruct/@PreDestroy), since this ensures that nothing will started until after all beans have been instantiated and wired together.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me check `thread-names`  during initialization. You partly mentioned this but let me confirm that my spring initialization is deterministic and successful in Spring 3.x and deterministic and `unsuccessful` in any of Spring 4.x (4.0 to 4.3); that's with zero code or bean definition changes during the 3.x and 4.x comparison.

Comment: Do you multiple Spring contexts, or some other way you can reduce the complexity by disabling some of the beans. If there are no additional threads, perhaps the randomness could come from a HashMap somewhere? Perhaps try a newer version of Spring. My best suggestion is to put a breakpoint where the exception is thrown, and then look at the call-stack when it breaks and look at how it got there, and look through the layers of spring until something stands out. It looks like you have some serious debugging to look forward to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will dig deeper. Unfortunately, there is no exception. Usually, Spring detects circular references, tries to resolve them, and finally finds a solution. Otherwise it throws an exception. In my case, Spring 4.x does not give up. It ends up retrying several thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

The core of it is as Strelok says, you are mixing annotations and xml config.

The point of the @Configuration annotation is to avoid xml. When you added the component scan for the package after removing SomeSpringConfiguration from xml.

You would start to create multiples of someDataSource, because it is defined in multiple places (@Bean annotation, and in xml).

Please avoid mixing annotations and xml, only use one of them and stick to that, and this problem will, if not resolved but at least much easier to spot.

If you can create an example project and upload it somewhere I can take a closer look if you are still having this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please note that the application has thousands of beans defined in/via `xml, @Component, and @Configuration`. All of them coexist. I agree that using only one of them is preferable but unfortunately, that's out of question in this large project. The main pain point here is that the exact same code works fine in Spring 3.2.x but not in any of Spring's 4.x.y.